# Replacing multimap with mapping an element to a collection of elements

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to map a meterId to a list of MeterBlinks that have that Id. I'm mainly confused on how to build the list up for the HashMap.put() call. Code below:

```
Map<String, List<MeterBlink>> IdToMetersMap = new HashMap<>();
for (MeterBlink meterBlink : createData()) {
    List<MeterBlink> meterBlinkList = new ArrayList<>();
    meterBlinkList.add(meterBlink);
    String meterId = meterBlink.getMeterId();
    idToMetersMap.put(meterId, meterBlinkList)
}
```

I think the issue is that I am creating a new list each time I iterate through but I am not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: Get the list from the map. If null, create it and add it to the map. Add your element to the list. Or simply keep using Guava. Multimap exists for good reasons.

Comment: You may try to use Collections.emptyList() instead of null, which will make your life easier when using your map. When it comes to filling, JB Nizet's idea will work nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the java8 answer, but here without java8 (without lambda expressions):

```
Map<String, List<MeterBlink>> idToMetersMap = new HashMap<>();
for (MeterBlink meterBlink : createData()) {
    String meterId = meterBlink.getMeterId();
    List<MeterBlink> meterBlinkList = idToMetersMap.get(meterId);
    //if List doesn't exist create it and put in Map
    if (meterBlinkList == null) {
        meterBlinkList = new ArrayList<>();
        idToMetersMap.put(meterId, meterBlinksList)
    }
    meterBlinkList.add(meterBlink);       
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) method added in jre 8:

```
Map<String, List<MeterBlink>> idToMetersMap = new HashMap<>();
for (MeterBlink meterBlink : createData()) {
    String meterId = meterBlink.getMeterId();
    idToMetersMap.computeIfAbsent(meterId, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(meterBlinks);
}
```

Another option in java 8:

```
Map<String, List<MeterBlink>> idToMetersMap = createData().stream()
                                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MeterBlink::getMeterId));
```

Comment: @peggy, do you mean that you cannot use java 8?

Comment: yes unfortunately. +1'd for the elegant answers though